# For which value of $x \in R $ the following series converges $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty n!x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For which value of $x \in R $ the following series converges

$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty n!x^n$

The series of the absolute values is $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty n! |x|^n$

and applying the root test:
$ lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{ n! |x|^n}= lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  (n!)^{ \frac{1}{n}} |x| =|x|<1 $

because I think that $ lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  (n!)^{ \frac{1}{n}}  =1 $

$(n*(n-1)*(n-2)...*3 *2* 1)^{ \frac{1}{n}}=n^{ \frac{1}{n}}*(n-1)^{ \frac{1}{n}}*(n-2)^{ \frac{1}{n}}*...*3^{ \frac{1}{n}}*2^{ \frac{1}{n}}*1^{ \frac{1}{n}} 
 \rightarrow 1*1*1*...*1*1*1=1$

while the solution should be $x=0$

Can someone help me to understant where is the mistake?

Comment: "because I think that $ lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  (n!)^{ \frac{1}{n}}  =1 $" Well, no. Please rethink this step.

Comment: Specifically: $$\log(n!^{1/n}) = \frac{1}{n} \log n! \operatorname*{=}_{\rm Stirling} \frac{1}{n} (n\log n + O(n)) = \log n + O(1)$$
so $ n!^{1/n} = e^{\log n + O(1)} = \Theta(n)$. This merrily goes to $\infty$.

Comment: What about the ratio test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your mistake:

> because I think that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  (n!)^{ \frac{1}{n}}  =1$

Actually, we have 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  (n!)^{ \frac{1}{n}}  = +\infty\,.$$
This is not hard to see e.g. using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) (or even more elementary, cruder inequalities on $\log n!$ will do):
$$
\log\left( (n!)^{ \frac{1}{n}} \right) = \frac{1}{n} \log n!
= \frac{1}{n}\left(n\log n +O(n)\right)
= \log n +O(1) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \infty\,.
$$
*(The above argument with Stirling's approximation actually yields $ (n!)^{ \frac{1}{n}} = \Theta(n)$, so it goes to $\infty$ at a linear rate.)*

Answer (score 0):

> *Can someone help me to understand where is the mistake?*

You have applied a limit rule concerning *finite* products to an *infinite* product, which is no longer true.

One may recall that
$$
\left(1+\frac1k \right)^k<e,\qquad k\ge1,
$$ then by multiplying this over $k=1,2,\cdots,n-1$, factors telescope, one obtains
$$
\frac{n^n}{n!}<e^n
$$ or

> $$
> \frac{n}{e}<(n!)^{\large\frac1n}
> $$

giving
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}(n!)^{\large\frac1n}=\infty.
$$